# How is i ever 10 after this for loop?

Tags: javascript

Looking at this code, if I console log `i` after the loop terminates, `i = 10` but I don't understand how.

`i` is set to `0` and then increments by one as long as `i < 10`, so it stops incrementing at `9`. So in the log within the loop, i counts from 0 - 9, but when I log `i` AFTER the loop terminates. It has become 10.

I don't understand how it goes from 9 - 10.

```
"use strict";

var foo = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    foo[i] = function() { return  i};
}
console.log(i);
```

Could anyone explain this to me? Thank you :)

Comment: Although I'm sure they're going to run into that problem later, this question *is not* a duplicate of the question about using loop variables in closures.

Comment: Wasn't actually a dupe of that question. However, it's answered simply by the fact that i++ increments your value of i. Once it is outside the valid range (i.e. 10, no longer < 10), then the loop exits. You then display the value of 10, after the loop has completed.

Comment: @MikeC, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `i = 9`, the loop increments it to `10`. Then it checks if `i < 10` which is false and hence your code exits the loop with the value `i = 10`.

Typically a loop executes in the order

1. Initialize loop variables
2. Check if condition is true.
3. Update the loop variablew

Answer (score 2):

You've got the order mixed up. Here's how it goes:

1. If `i < 10`
2. Execute loop body
3. Update `i` (`i++`)
4. Return to `1`

So the way your loop ends is that `i++` moves the value up to `10` then checks the condition. Since `i` is no longer less than 10, the loop ends.

Comment: @LeMoi Glad I could help :) Heads up! Since you're using `i` inside of those functions you're making, you're going to run into a very common problem. [Check out this question for an explanation of how to deal with it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example?lq=1) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have a console.log on your last line.  `i` gets assigned `10` (by adding 1) and then the loop evaluates to see if it should continue, but `i` has to surpass 9 to stop the loop.

Answer (score 0):

After the last time through the loop, `i++` runs one last time, so `i` is 10. Then the `i < 10` condition fails, so the loop exits.

Answer (score 0):

loop exits after it reaches 10
see the condition  i < 10

sry for the typo

Comment: Loop exits after it reaches 10 because 10 is not less than 10.

Comment: sry thats correct, loop exits after it reaches 10 see the condition i < 10